# Simple navigation bar (Beginner)

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, nav

I am just learning html and my teacher in my software development class told me I should start to experiment with programming on my own time and so I decided I should try to make a simple website. As you can see, I haven't got very far and have been stuck on figuring out how to make the nav bar. I want for each box on the nav bar to be clickable and able to link to the correct webpage. I did try putting the a tags before each li and not having an image map, which does what I want as far as the boxes being able to link to the appropriate webpages, but there was a space between each box, which I don't want,which also resulted in the 6th box being pushed under the 1st box. Using the image map, there are no links and when I inspect the element, it says the image map is 0 x 0. Let me know what I'm doing wrong with the nav bar or if there is a better method to do this.
HTML:

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
}
#name {
  font-size: 19pt;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(wood.png);
  height: 81px;
  display: block;
}
h2.Title {
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  left: 535;
  top: 1;
}
h2.TitleShadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 533;
  top: 0;
  color: #368BC1;
}
#navbar {
  display: table;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 65;
}
#navbar li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 30px;
  width: 16.666666667%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Noah's Sports Cards</title>
  <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, tv, tty" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="name">
    <h2 class="Title">Noah's Sports Cards</h2>
    <h2 class="TitleShadow">Noah's Sports Cards</h2>
  </div>
  <ul id="navbar" usemap="#navMap">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Albums</li>
    <li>Random</li>
    <li>Memorbilia</li>
    <li>Tools</li>
    <li>About</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <map id="navMap">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0, 82, 227.667, 113" href="home.htm" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="227.667, 82, 455.334, 113" href="albums.htm" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="455.334, 82, 683.001, 113" href="random.htm" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="683.001, 82, 910.668, 113" href="memorbilia.htm" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="910.668, 82, 1138.335, 113" href="tools.htm" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="1138.335, 82, 1366, 113" href="about.htm" />
    </map>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example

Comment: Why not create a `ul` and use `display:table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use maps, your page semantics will be lost afterwards.
The same piece of code with links (just the `<ul>` section):

```
<ul id="navbar">
  <li>
    <a href="home.htm">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="albums.htm">Albums</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="random.htm">Random</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="memorbilia.htm">Memorbilia</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="tools.htm">Tools</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="about.htm">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then in the CSS, just add this line to add full width to the link and parse it as a block, besides removing the blue color and underline:

```
#navbar li a { color: #000; text-decoration: none; width: 100%; display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest that you start writing your code with correct indentation. It is much harder to read code like this, for yourself and for others reading your code.

To create links in your nav-bar, simply do something like this:

```
 <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="album.html">Album</a></li>
    <li><a href="random.html">Random</a></li>
    <li><a href="memorbilia.html">Memorbilia</a></li>
    <li><a href="tools.html">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you're having problems with space between elements and positions of elements, it's simply a question of CSS.

Copying your code into https://jsfiddle.net/ produces a clustery page, so it is not easy telling what your problem is.

If you want better help I suggest that you edit your post and provide with better information and remove the unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Navbar

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="navbar-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggler" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggler="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                    </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another Action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">One More</a>
                        </div>
                </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>    
    </nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you edited your answer to add an explanation to go along with your code snippet.